# YASR - Yet another search and replace question

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml-sdk, openxml

Environment: asp.net c# openxml

Ok, so I've been reading a ton of snippets and trying to recreate the wheel, but I'm hoping that somone can help me get to my desination faster.  I have multiple documents that I need to merge together... check... I'm able to do that with openxml sdk. Birds are singing, sun is shining so far.  Now that I have the document the way I want it, I need to search and replace text and/or content controls.

I've tried using my own text - {replace this} but when I look at the xml (rename docx to zip and view the file), the { is nowhere near the text.  So I either need to know how to protect that within the doucment so they don't diverge or I need to find another way to search and replace.

I'm able to search/replace if it is an xml file, but then I'm back to not being able to combine the doucments easily.

Code below... and as I mentioned... document merge works fine... just need to replace stuff.

*** Update *** changed my replace call to go after the tag instead of regex.  I have the right info now, but the .Replace call doesn't seem to want to work.  Last four lines are for validation that I was seeing the right tag contents.  I simply want to replace those contents now.

```
    protected void exeProcessTheDoc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string doc1 = Server.MapPath("~/Templates/doc1.docx");
        string doc2 = Server.MapPath("~/Templates/doc2.docx");
        string final_doc = Server.MapPath("~/Templates/extFinal.docx");

        File.Delete(final_doc);
        File.Copy(doc1, final_doc);

        using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(final_doc, true))
        {
            string altChunkId = "AltChunkId2";

            MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
            AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(doc2, FileMode.Open))
            chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
            AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
            altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
            mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
            mainPart.Document.Save();
        }
        exeSearchReplace(final_doc);
    }

    public static void GetPropertyFromDocument(string document, string outdoc)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlProperties = new XmlDocument();

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, false))
        {
            ExtendedFilePropertiesPart appPart = wordDoc.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart;

            xmlProperties.Load(appPart.GetStream());
        }
        XmlNodeList chars = xmlProperties.GetElementsByTagName("Company");
        chars.Item(0).InnerText.Replace("{ClientName}", "Penn Inc.");

        StreamWriter sw;
        sw = File.CreateText(outdoc);
        sw.WriteLine(chars.Item(0).InnerText);
        sw.Close();
     }    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this right, you have something like "{replace me}" in a .docx and then when you loop through the XML, you're finding things like `<t>{replace</t><t> me</><t>}</t>` or some such havoc. Now, with XML like that, it's impossible to create a routine that will replace "{replace me}".

If that's the case, then it's very, very likely related to the fact that it's considered a proofing error. i.e. it's misspelled as far as Word is concerned. The cause of it is that you've opened the document in Word and have proofing turned on. As such, the text is marked as "isDirty" and split up into different runs.

The two ways about fixing this are:

1. Client-side. In Word, just make sure all proofing errors are either corrected or ignored.
2. Format-side. Use the **MarkupSimplifier** tool that is part of Open XML Package Editor Power Tool for Visual Studio 2010 to fix this outside of the client. Eric White has a great (and timely for you - just a few days old) write up here on it: [Getting Started with Open XML PowerTools Markup Simplifier](http://ericwhite.com/blog/2011/03/09/getting-started-with-open-xml-powertools-markup-simplifier/)

Comment: On the right track.  The prooferr was defintely part of it.  The Markup Simplifier didn't help me but was able to find/fix the separation issue.  I still can't seem to find the field and replace it though.  Any ideas on my search and replace code?

Comment: It's hard to say. I'm not sure I would try using a StreamReader for this. Why not just pull this as XML and get all the `.Value` to search for your RegEx text and then at the end do as you were doing and and `.Save` it. Here's an example with PowerPoint and VB.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903142/is-it-possible-to-update-a-powerpoint-slide-with-new-data-in-c/4504970#4504970 using Linq to XML.

Comment: @petronius31: just saw your update. three things: **1)** your `using` statement needs to include `XmlNodeList chars = xmlProperties.GetElementsByTagName("Company");
        chars.Item(0).InnerText.Replace("{ClientName}", "Penn Inc.");`, **2)** you could use Linq instead - I find it to be much easier and **3)**. You'll want to do `xmlProperties.Save` instead of stream reading saving it.

Comment: getting closer.  changed the second line below and now I can output to the text file the corrected value but I haven't been able to figurre out how to update the document itselfe.

Comment: getting closer.  changed the second line below and now I can output to the text file the corrected value but I haven't been able to figurre out how to update the document itself.              XmlNodeList chars = xmlProperties.GetElementsByTagName("Company");
            chars.Item(0).InnerText = chars.Item(0).InnerText.Replace("{ClientName}", "Penn Inc.");

Comment: `xmlProperties.Save` inside of the `using` should save the document with the updates.

Comment: xmlProperties.Save what?  can't just leave it at that... has to have something.  I've tried xmlProperties.Save(apart.ToString()); and xmlProperties.Save(appPart.ToString(chars.Item(0).InnerText));

Comment: Sorry, it should be `xmlProperties.Save(appPart.GetStream)`. I haven't tried this with `XDocument` (that's the type you currently have `xmlProperties` as), but I have done it with `XElement` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search and replace text in a WordprocessingML document, there is a fairly easy algorithm that you can use:

- Break all runs into runs of a single character.  This includes runs that have special characters such as a line break, carriage return, or hard tab.
- It is then pretty easy to find a set of runs that match the characters in your search string.
- Once you have identified a set of runs that match, then you can replace that set of runs with a newly created run (which has the run properties of the run containing the first character that matched the search string).
- After replacing the single-character runs with a newly created run, you can then consolidate adjacent runs with identical formatting.

I've written a blog post and recorded a screen-cast that walks through this algorithm.

Blog post: http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/2011/05/12/148357.aspx
Screen cast: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w128hJUu3GM

-Eric