# Using C# & Powerpoint OpenXML, is it possible to change the font size and color of text

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I am using openXML and C# to generate a powerpoint slide but I can't seem to figure out how to change / set the text size and color.  Is this possible and are there any example as I can't seem to find any with googling?

I am building out a table (similar to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/08/13/adding-repeating-data-to-powerpoint.aspx) and I want to change a number of things in each cell (fontsize, font color, backcolor of cell).

Comment: @DustinDavis: How was this comment anything but useless noise? That's not how SO works, and you should know better; this is not your first time here.

Comment: not sure what this whole @DustinDavis thing is about, but @ooo would you be willing to look at VB.NET code? You said it was fine on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903142/is-it-possible-to-update-a-powerpoint-slide-with-new-data-in-c, but never accepted the answer there, so I'm not sure if answering in VB.NET works for you or not.

Comment: @Otaku - im happy to look at VB.net code if you have any samples

Comment: Great! Please revisit the other thread first and at the very least let me know if the code does/doesn't work for you, why, what needs to change, etc. Then I'd be happy to happy to help on this one.

Comment: @Otaku - the link on the other thread doesn't answer this question.  it just replaces existing text in hard coded tables.  It doesn't maniupulate any of the text formatting.

Comment: Guess I'm not sure why you put it as an answer then.

Comment: @Otaku - in the other thread my question was first about just dynamically adding rows to a table.  This link was a good start that helped me out.  it didn't unfortunately do any of the formatting changes.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't referring to that when when i asked you to revisit it, i was referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903142/is-it-possible-to-update-a-powerpoint-slide-with-new-data-in-c

Comment: @Otaku - i have marked that OTHER question as accepted. i am still stuck on changing font sizes and colors.. any suggestions

Comment: @ooo: Just a quick question before answering - are you looking to change the font/color for a particular text run, a paragraph, a theme or the presentation default? they all have very different answers.

Comment: @Otaku - i am building out a table (similar to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/08/13/adding-repeating-data-to-powerpoint.aspx) and i want to change a number of things in each cell (fontsize, font color, backcolor of cell)   . are any of these possible ??

Comment: @ooo: I've looked at this more and here's the deal. It's totally possible, but like other text editing in DrawingML (this isn't PresentationML) it can be quite complex. I'm afraid an explanation would be incredibly long and take quite a while to put together. Maybe the SDK would make this easier - I don't use the SDK so I'm not sure. Sorry I can't be of much more help here. I'll keep looking around to see if anyone has addressed this before.

Comment: @Otaku - thanks for your reply.. i find it a bit crazy that something that seems so straight forward (change font size and color) is such a complicated task that can't be answered by anyone on the internet :( ??

Comment: I was only awarded half the bounty by default (special thanks to those who voted for my answer).  Why didn't you award the full amount to someone?  If there was something about our answers you didn't like, could you please comment them with your concerns?  Thank you.

Comment: @leora: Hi i am doing same i.e generating ppt, but theres one issue the source code missing in the link you have provided. If you mail me sample code would be better or the template.ppt also work for me. my id satindersinght@gmail.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your comments state this Formatting is for a Table inside a PowerPoint slide.

**Assumptions**
I am assuming you have already created the table, table rows, table cells, and display text.
Also assuming you have everything working and now you want to add formatting.

If you want to format your Text and Cells, you may do so using the following:

```
//Create the TableCell for the PowerPoint table you are building.
A.TableCell tableCell3 = new A.TableCell();
A.TextBody textBody5 = new A.TextBody();
A.BodyProperties bodyProperties5 = new A.BodyProperties();//Created but not modified.
A.ListStyle listStyle5 = new A.ListStyle();//Created but not modified.
A.Paragraph paragraph5 = new A.Paragraph();

//First Word: "Hello" with Font-Size 60x and Font-Color Green.
A.Run run1 = new A.Run();
A.RunProperties runProperties1 = new A.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 6000, Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };//Set Font-Size to 60px.
A.SolidFill solidFill1 = new A.SolidFill();
A.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex1 = new A.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "00B050" };//Set Font-Color to Green (Hex "00B050").
solidFill1.Append(rgbColorModelHex1);
runProperties1.Append(solidFill1);
A.Text text1 = new A.Text();
text1.Text = "Hello";
run1.Append(runProperties1);
run1.Append(text1);

//Second Word: "World" with Font-Size 60x and Font-Color Blue.
A.Run run2 = new A.Run();
A.RunProperties runProperties2 = new A.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 6000, Dirty = false, SmartTagClean = false };//Set Font-Size to 60px.
A.SolidFill solidFill2 = new A.SolidFill();
A.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex2 = new A.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "0070C0" };//Set Font-Color to Blue (Hex "0070C0").
solidFill2.Append(rgbColorModelHex2);
runProperties2.Append(solidFill2);
A.Text text2 = new A.Text();
text2.Text = " World";
run2.Append(runProperties2);
run2.Append(text2);

//This element specifies the text run properties that are to be used if another run is inserted after the last run specified.
//This effectively saves the run property state so that it can be applied when the user enters additional text.
//If this element is omitted, then the application can determine which default properties to apply.
//It is recommended that this element be specified at the end of the list of text runs within the paragraph so that an orderly list is maintained.
//  Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.endparagraphrunproperties.aspx
//Set the default formatting for words entered after "Hello World" with Font-Size 60x and Font-Color Blue.
A.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties5 = new A.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 6000, Dirty = false };//Set Font-Size to 60px.
A.SolidFill solidFill3 = new A.SolidFill();
A.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex3 = new A.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "0070C0" };//Set Font-Color to Blue (Hex "0070C0").
solidFill3.Append(rgbColorModelHex3);
endParagraphRunProperties5.Append(solidFill3);

paragraph5.Append(run1);//Append Run: "Hello".
paragraph5.Append(run2);//Append Run: " World".
paragraph5.Append(endParagraphRunProperties5);//Append formmatting for any text the user may enter after the words "Hello World".
textBody5.Append(bodyProperties5);//Created but not modified.
textBody5.Append(listStyle5);//Created but not modified.
textBody5.Append(paragraph5);//Append Paragraph: "Hello World"

//TableCell Properties.  Set Background-Color to Red (Hex "FF0000").
A.TableCellProperties tableCellProperties3 = new A.TableCellProperties();
A.SolidFill solidFill4 = new A.SolidFill();
A.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex4 = new A.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "FF0000" };//Red Background for Single TableCell.
solidFill4.Append(rgbColorModelHex4);
tableCellProperties3.Append(solidFill4);//Append Red Background.

tableCell3.Append(textBody5);
tableCell3.Append(tableCellProperties3);
```

I cheated and used the "[Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)".
I simply created a new PowerPoint file, added a table, and edited the 3rd Cell.
Then I ran the SDK tool and reflected the code on "*[]/ppt/presentation.xml*".
I added comments to the reflected code so that you may understand it better.

Answer (score 4):

As another user pointed out this is possible in ML.  Here is a solution I used to solve this problem:

```
// Assume we are adding a A.TableCell to A.TableRow...
A.TableCell tc = new A.TableCell(
new A.TextBody(
new A.BodyProperties(),
new A.Paragraph(new A.Run( 
// -> Add the RunProperties as additional Element to A.Run constructor:
new A.RunProperties() { FontSize = 600 }, new A.Text("some text") ) ) ),
new A.TableCellProperties() );

// Now add the cell to a A.TableRow instance...
```

When creating an A.TableCell cell for appending to the row of an A.Table, I added a RunProperty Element to the A.Run nesting the A.Text for the cell, and I instantiated it with the FontSize attribute set accordingly: `{ FontSize = 600 }`.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the object for the run or paragraph you wish to manipulate, you can add whatever styling you want to the run or paragraph properties.